# Create a list and give accounts from there discord.js v14

Tags: discord.js

I need create a account list and when members use this command bot need give 1 account to member via dm. Note: 1 account - 1 member, i cant give 1 account to many members.

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  if (
    message.content.toLowerCase() === "account" ) {
    message.reply("Account sent");
    message.author.send("account name:password");
  }
});
```

How can i create a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your accounts in an array, then use a variable to keep track of which index to send.

```js
const accounts = ["name:password", ...];

let i = 0;
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "account" ) {
    if (i >= (accounts.length - 1)) return message.reply("Out of accounts");

    await message.author.send(`account ${accounts[i]}`);
    await message.reply("Account sent");
    
    i++;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes now its working. Can i take datas from another file like exe?

Comment: Yes, by either using `export/import` or `module.exports` and `require`